# UpdatePolicy in Autoscaling group not working correctly for AWS CloudFormation update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am using AWS CloudFormation to launch my server stack. I have created a LaunchConfig and then AutoScaling group that uses the above launchconfig. I have set CreationPolicy which waits for signals from my EC2 instances which creating the CF stack.

Also, i have set UpdatePolicy to AutoScaling group to wait for the signals from new instances if i update the CF stack with more desired number of instances as follows:

```
"UpdatePolicy" : {
        "AutoScalingRollingUpdate" : {
            "PauseTime" : "PT10M",
            "WaitOnResourceSignals" : "true"
        }
    }
```

According to the above, CF should wait for signals from newly launched instances (or get timed out) before setting the status of CF stack as "UPDATE_COMPLE".

But it is not working as explained above. The status of CF stack immediately changes to "UPDATE_COMPLE" w/o waiting for signals.

Please help.

Comment: Are you able to confirm new instances are being launched when you run the stack update?

Comment: Yes. The new instances are getting launched, but CF stack status immediately changes to "UPDATE_COMPLETE" and it does not wait for the new instances to come up.

Comment: I've created a similar question where I've added reproducibility steps and more information on diagnosis. Hopefully it won't fall into the void for a year like this one did. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017696/cloudformation-autoscalinggroup-not-waiting-for-signal-on-scale-up

Comment: What type of change are you making to the stack? My understanding is, `AutoScalingRollingUpdate` only needs to wait for things like `LaunchConfiguration` changes, or Availability Zone changes.